# Question about full stack Cypress testing

Tags: testing, next.js, cypress, github-actions, web-api-testing

I'm using Cypress, NextJS (frontend), Django, and Github Actions. My question is how does it work to test my API calls if I don't have a server running on Github but my page initially pulls from my Django API. Is the only way to run a fixture or would it be better to have a .env.testing with a live testing database and build it on GitHub Actions? Thanks for the help in advance.

I'm getting this error

- error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80
  at AxiosError.from (/home/runner/work/sso-google/sso-google/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:836:14)

Here is my API call

```
export const getServerSideProps = 
wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => async (context) => {
const request = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_API}/jobs/home/`, 
headers);

return {
  props: {}
 };
});
```

Here is my workflow.

```
name: Vercel Production Deployment
env:
  VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
  VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  Cypress-Test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout GitCode
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
 
      - name: Run Cypress Test
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
        with:
          start: yarn run build:prod && yarn run dev
          command: yarn run cypress:run
          browser: chrome
  Deploy-Production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Vercel CLI
        run: npm install --global vercel@latest
      - name: Pull Vercel Environment Information
        run: vercel pull --yes --environment=production --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_SECRET }}
      - name: Build Project Artifacts
        run: vercel build --prod --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_SECRET }}
      - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
        run: vercel deploy --prebuilt --prod --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_SECRET }}
```